# How to enable those suggestions on VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

How to enable those kinda suggestions in string ?
Name of the extension? Maybe I need to edit in settings file? Something? Please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check with Visual Studio Code IntelliSense.

You can **trigger IntelliSense** in any editor window by typing `Ctrl+Space` or by typing a trigger character (such as the dot character (.) in JavaScript).